# rendering foreign keys as a pulldown in web2py appadmin

Tags: web2py, pydal

part of my web2py database schema looks like so:

```
db.define_table('asset',
    Field('name', unique=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('description', 'text')
)

db.define_table('wallet',
    Field('name', unique=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('description', type='text')
)

db.define_table('wallet_asset',
    Field('wallet_id', 'reference wallet'),
    Field('asset_id', 'reference asset')
)
```

When I visit `appadmin` to enter a new `wallet_asset` record, I would like for the `wallet_id` and `asset_id` fields to be pulldowns that render the names of those referenced tables.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format` record representation at the time of defining tables.

Read [format: Record representation](http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#format-Record-representation)

Your schema will look like this:

```
db.define_table('asset',
    Field('name', unique=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('description', 'text'),
    format='%(name)s'
)

db.define_table('wallet',
    Field('name', unique=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('description', type='text'),
    format='%(name)s'
)
```