# Rendering the foreign tables of foreign tables as strings in a pulldown in web2py appadmin

Tags: web2py, pydal

Following up on [rendering foreign keys as a pulldown in web2py
appadmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40252123/rendering-foreign-keys-as-a-pulldown-in-web2py-appadmin),
I would like to be able to render references of references as
strings in pulldowns.

In other words, the previous question dealt with how to render the
foreign keys of a table as a pulldown. This question deals with the
foreign keys of the foreign keys.

I am now able to render the foreign keys of the table
`wallet_asset`:

```
db.define_table('wallet_asset',
    Field('wallet_id', 'reference wallet'),
    Field('asset_id', 'reference asset'),
)
```

by defining the referenced tables like so:

```
db.define_table('asset',
    Field('name', unique=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('description', 'text'),
                format='%(name)s'
)

db.define_table('wallet',
    Field('name', unique=True, requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),
    Field('description', type='text'),
    format='%(name)s'
)
```

but now I want to have a table `user_wallet_asset` :

```
db.define_table('user_wallet_asset',
    Field('user_id', 'reference auth_user'),
    Field('wallet_asset_id', 'reference wallet_asset'),
    Field('address')
)
```

And when I enter records using AppAdmin, I want the field
`wallet_asset_id` to render in a pulldown as a string based on the
representation of foreign keys in the tables `wallet and`asset`,
something like:

> asset.name is held in wallet.name

The reason this is not straightforward is that `user_wallet_asset`
references `wallet_asset` which then references `wallet` and `asset`.

Presumably the final solution looks something like this:

```
db.define_table('wallet_asset',
    Field('wallet_id', 'reference wallet'),
    Field('asset_id', 'reference asset'),
    format='%(asset_id).name is held in %(wallet_id).name'
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `format` argument can take a function that generates the values you want:

```
db.define_table('wallet_asset',
    Field('wallet_id', 'reference wallet'),
    Field('asset_id', 'reference asset'),
    format=lambda r: '%s is held in %s' % (r.asset_id.name, r.wallet_id.name))
```

Note, `r.asset_id.name` and `r.wallet_id.name` involve [recursive selects](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/06/the-database-abstraction-layer#Recursive-selects), so when a dropdown is generated for the `db.user_wallet_asset.wallet_asset_id` field, there will be two database selects for each item in the dropdown.

For further details, you may find [this answer](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/web2py/igg4X_X8cQQ/5AlWJKE5FYQJ) helpful.